# Can page be used synonymous for section in webdesign?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

On some freelancer pages, webdesigner are payed per section of a webpage. However, I found many webdesigner who use `pages` or `screen` synonymously for `section`, especially non-native freelancer from Sri Lanka / Pakistan / Bangladesh. I wonder, is this correct usage? Or is this a  common non-native English speaker issue?

Example: One webpage with 3 sections:

[image]

Some examples of webdesign offers on freelancer page:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well this answers the technical problem that you have, but yes, `page` `screen` and `section` all have rather different meanings to me, as an IT Pro.

However the problem that you have, is that the meaning depends on context (doesn't everything?) So, for example, a single PHP file may produce every single visible page on a particular website, so to the site owner, there may be thousands of `pages`, but to a back-end developer there is only one page, producing loads of `screens`.

'Section' is a little harder - it could mean a small part of a page (there is an HTML element precisely for this) or it could be the equivalent of a chapter in a book, i.e. a whole bunch of URL's.
In older (pre-internet) applications, the usual term for what we might now call a `page` is `screen`, since the exact size of the screen was usually well defined.